# Using Terraform to create AWS ECS with target group always timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

## Terraform Version

v0.11.3

## Affected Resources

- aws_ecs_service
- aws_ecs_task_definition
- aws_alb
- aws_alb_target_group
- aws_alb_listener

## Error

I'm setting up an ECS cluster with currently one service.  Had several issues getting the service up without breaking, but now my service can't seem to keep a container running.

`service phoenix-web (instance i-079707fc669361a81) (port 80) is unhealthy in target-group tgqaphoenix-web due to (reason Request timed out)`

### Related?

Once my resources are up, I can't seem to find a public dns link on any instance or on the vpc gateway

[image: Service phoenix-web target group is unhealthy]

#### main.tf for my ECS Service module:

```
data "template_file" "ecs_task_definition_config" {
  template = "${file("config/ecs-task.json")}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "phoenix-web" {
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  family                = "nginx-phoenix-task"
  container_definitions = "${data.template_file.ecs_task_definition_config.rendered}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"

  tags {
    Name        = "sg${var.name}LoadBalancer"
    Project     = "${var.name}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "app_lb_https_ingress" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 80
  to_port     = 80
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.main.id}"
}

resource "aws_alb" "main" {
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.main.id}"]
  subnets         = ["${var.public_subnet_ids}"]
  name            = "alb-${var.environment}-${var.name}"

  access_logs {
    bucket = "${var.access_log_bucket}"
    prefix = "${var.access_log_prefix}"
  }

  tags {
    Name        = "alb-${var.environment}-${var.name}"
    Project     = "${var.name}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "main" {
  name = "tg${var.environment}${var.name}"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
    interval            = "30"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    timeout             = "3"
    path                = "/healthz"
    unhealthy_threshold = "2"
  }

  port     = "80"
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = "${var.vpc_id}"

  tags {
    Name        = "tg${var.environment}${var.name}"
    Project     = "${var.name}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_alb.main"]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "https" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.main.id}"
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.main.id}"
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  name                               = "${var.name}"
  cluster                            = "${var.environment}"
  task_definition                    = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.phoenix-web.id}"
  desired_count                      = "${var.desired_count}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = "${var.deployment_min_healthy_percent}"
  deployment_maximum_percent         = "${var.deployment_max_percent}"
  iam_role                           = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-role.id}"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.main.id}"
    container_name   = "phoenix-web"
    container_port   = "80"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_iam_role.ecs-role", "null_resource.alb_exists"]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecs-policy" {
  name = "ecs-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-role.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:CreateCluster",
        "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
        "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
        "ecs:Poll",
        "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
        "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
        "ecs:Submit*",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  depends_on = ["aws_iam_role.ecs-role"]
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-role" {
  name = "ecs-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "main" {
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.environment}/${var.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  role_arn           = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-role.arn}"
  min_capacity       = "${var.min_count}"
  max_capacity       = "${var.max_count}"

  depends_on = [
    "aws_ecs_service.service",
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "alb_exists" {
  triggers {
    alb_name = "${aws_alb_target_group.main.id}"
  }
}
```

#### main.tf for my ECS cluster module

```
module "s3-log-storage" {
  source  = "cloudposse/s3-log-storage/aws"
  version = "0.1.3"

  # insert the 3 required variables here
  namespace = "mmt-ecs"
  stage     = "${var.environment}"
  name      = "logs-bucket"
  policy    = <<POLICY
{
  "Id": "Policy1519319575520",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1519319570434",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectTagging",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mmt-ecs-qa-logs-bucket/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

module "network" {
  source               = "../network"
  environment          = "${var.environment}"
  vpc_cidr             = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  public_subnet_cidrs  = "${var.public_subnet_cidrs}"
  private_subnet_cidrs = "${var.private_subnet_cidrs}"
  availability_zones   = "${var.availability_zones}"
  depends_id           = ""
}

module "ecs_instances" {
  source = "../ecs_instances"

  environment             = "${var.environment}"
  cluster                 = "${var.cluster}"
  instance_group          = "${var.instance_group}"
  private_subnet_ids      = "${module.network.private_subnet_ids}"
  aws_ami                 = "${var.ecs_aws_ami}"
  instance_type           = "${var.instance_type}"
  max_size                = "${var.max_size}"
  min_size                = "${var.min_size}"
  desired_capacity        = "${var.desired_capacity}"
  vpc_id                  = "${module.network.vpc_id}"
  iam_instance_profile_id = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.id}"
  key_name                = "${var.key_name}"
  load_balancers          = "${var.load_balancers}"
  depends_id              = "${module.network.depends_id}"
  custom_userdata         = "${var.custom_userdata}"
  cloudwatch_prefix       = "${var.cloudwatch_prefix}"
}

module "web-phoenix-service" {
  source = "../services/web-phoenix"


  environment = "${var.environment}"
  vpc_id = "${module.network.vpc_id}"
  public_subnet_ids = "${module.network.public_subnet_ids}"
  name = "phoenix-web"
  deployment_max_percent = "200"
  deployment_min_healthy_percent = "100"
  max_count = "2"
  min_count = "1"
  desired_count = "1"
  ecs_service_role_name = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.id}"
  access_log_bucket = "${module.s3-log-storage.bucket_id}"
  access_log_prefix = "ALB"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.cluster}"
}
```

Comment: is your health check path "/healthz" valid?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the application health check is failing i.e. /healthz. You start debugging issue like below:

1) Spin up a container in your local and check whether it is working or not. Per your health check info above, you should be able to access application like http://someip:port/healthz
If this works 
2) Are you exposing port 80 while building docker image ? Check in docker file.
3) if above two steps seems okay, then try accessing your application by using EC S instance ip as soon as task is running.
http://ecsinstanceip:port/healthz .
4) If 3 also works, they try increasing the health check timeout period so that the application gets more time to pass its health check..

Comment: Check out https://puu.sh/zu8hW/136a5101eb.png

Since I can see /healthz it should be working and the port is exposed.

I grabbed the image and ran:
`docker run -ti -p 8093:80 00000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myrepo:latest`

Am I supposed to add the response code in the body, or just 'OK'?

Comment: Also, should I be seeing the ECS instance IP on the container instance?

https://puu.sh/zu8oQ/55c2ca3a1d.png

Answer (score 0):

#### Clue 1

Make sure that the ECS container instance's security group is able to accept ports 1024-65535 inside the VPN (don't open it for the outside world)

#### Clue 2

On the task definition for the `portMappings` specify it like:

```
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "hostPort": 0,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "containerPort": 80 
    }
  ],
```

Note here:
`containerPort` is what you `expose` from your container, where you app is listening with its healthcheck
`hostPort` would be what port you bind for forwarding on the host. Leave it 0 an it will be automatically assigned by ECS, that's why you need to open 1024-65535 on the SG. This is needed so you will be able to run the same task definition multiple times on the same instance (scale horizontally).